# Падает mysql сервер при запросе Alter Table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Использую команду `ALTER TABLE`. Вроде всё просто. Но на локальной системе (тот же phpmyadmin) не ругается. А на сервере, где плюс к этом установлен движок VestaCP, выдаёт `403 Forbidden` и после того, как перестаёт думать, что у меня нет прав для просмотра, не даёт мне посмотреть на свою таблицу. Просто `загрузка` и снова та же ошибка, либо 504.

Answer (score 1):

*`Изменено 3.05.2018`*

Всё просто. Я выполнял это действие с активным соединением (от бота, там постоянное соединение). Выключил бота, проверил. Всё работает исправно.

Answer (score 0):

`VestaCP` и `PHPMyAdmin` тут ни причём. Смотрите на права пользователя.
Если думаете что проблема в `PHPMyAdmin` то проверьте через `SSH` подключиться к `MySQL` серверу и выполнить запрос.